# Чи можна в українській мові сказати одним словом «захід сонця», так як в російській «закат»?

Tags: словосполучення, словотворення

В російській мові є слово «закат». В українській використовують «захід сонця». Чи є відповідник, який буде синонімом і складатися всього з одного слова?

Якщо такого немає, то чи було б важливо створити таке слово, для того щоб розвивати мову?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Прямим відповідником російському *закат* є ***за́хід***. Проблема в тому, що це слово має багато значень: це не лише природне явище чи частина доби, а й сторона світу та просто дія/засіб (як у «запобіжні заходи»). Утім, якщо контекст очевидний, то пояснювати «…сонця» необов'язково.

Також рос. «на закате» можна сказати одним словом ***[навза́ходи/навза́ході](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=53479&page=1705)/[надза́ходи/надза́ході](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=220298&page=1726)*** (оскільки щодо сторони світу й дій/засобів цей прислівник не вживається, то пояснення «…сонця» тут точно необов'язкове, хоча теж можливе).

Також можна сказати:

- ***[[вечі́рня] зоря́](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=37916&page=1186)***;
- ***[смерка́ння](http://sum.in.ua/s/smerkannja)***.

<sub>Останнє запитання залишу без відповіді, бо недостатньо компетентний, щоб на нього відповідати.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[За́гра́ва](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F_(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0)) — сяяння небосхилу під час заходу і сходу сонця.

[Зірниця](https://sum.in.ua/s/zirnycja) - яскраве освітлення горизонту перед сходом і після заходу сонця.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/4052)